# passing values to interactive fortran program using echo command

Tags: fortran

A fortran program requires three inputs to be passed interactively:

First input is just letter "D", second input is a file "A.cpt", and third input is a name for the output file that can be for example "B.out".

I have been trying to use echo command, but it is not working:

```
echo "D\nA.cpt\nB.out" | ./fortran_program
```

Any ideas?

**UPDATE**:

When using EOF, as suggested below, the program is going to an infinite loop repeating the following lines:

```
Please try again!
Please enter input binary hydra/quanta plot (old) filename
defaults <dotsurface_0_165.qpt> ext:<.qpt> (abort by EXIT or ^D) :  Sorry unable to open file: D.qpt
               or file: D
Please try again!
Please enter input binary hydra/quanta plot (old) filename
defaults <dotsurface_0_165.qpt> ext:<.qpt> (abort by EXIT or ^D) :  Sorry unable to open file: D.qpt
```

The source code for this program is on Github if that helps:

https://github.com/osmart/hole2/blob/master/src/qpt_conv.f

Comment: Would the intrinsic function `get_command_argument` work for your needs, or is it necessary to use (bash)?

Comment: When typing `D`, the program then expects a filename as the next argument. `input`, for instance, for the file `input.qpt`. Your second argument being `A`, the program looks for the file `A.qpt`.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using `bash` (or similar), I think `echo -e` or `printf` will be useful (but please check [this page](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88307/escape-sequences-with-echo-e-in-different-shells) also). For example,  either of

```
echo -e "D\nA.cpt\nB.out" | ./a.out
printf "D\nA.cpt\nB.out" | ./a.out
```

gives

```
str(1) = D         
str(2) = A.cpt     
str(3) = B.out
```

(for `a.out` generated from `test.f90` below). Another approach may be to use ["here document"](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/here-docs.html), e.g.

```
./a.out <<EOF
D
A.cpt
B.out
EOF
```

which I often use in a bash script (because the input part becomes more readable and looks like a separate input file).

```
!! test.f90
program main
    implicit none
    character(10) :: str( 3 )

    read *, str( 1 )
    read *, str( 2 )
    read *, str( 3 )

    print *, "str(1) = ", str(1)
    print *, "str(2) = ", str(2)
    print *, "str(3) = ", str(3)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can use actual line breaks in the echo command:

```
user@host$ echo "1                             
2
3" | ./test_echo 
           1           2           3
user@host$
```

When you type "enter" after `echo "1`, you can keep on entering the quote-delimited string.